# Nuxt: Cookies from API call not set

Tags: nuxt.js, nestjs

I am using NuxtJS 3 and NestJS. In NestJS I have the following API endpoint:

```
  @HttpCode(200)
  @UseGuards(LocalAuthenticationGuard)
  @Post('login')
  async logIn(@Req() request: RequestWithUser) {
    const { user } = request;
    const accessTokenCookie = `Authentication=AWFWAFEA; HttpOnly; Path=/; Max-Age=${this.configService.get('JWT_ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRATION_TIME')}`;
    const refreshTokenCookie = `Refresh=GBSRGRSERQ; HttpOnly; Path=/; Max-Age=${this.configService.get('JWT_REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRATION_TIME')}`;

    request.res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', [
      accessTokenCookie,
      refreshTokenCookie
    ]);

    const response = {
      access: true,
      user: user.id
    };



    return response;
  }
```

I am calling this API endpoint via a NuxtJS server route in */api/auth/login*:

```
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
    const { username, password } = await readBody(event);

    const response = await $fetch('http://backend:PORT/auth/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: {
            "username": username,
            "password": password
        }
    });
    return response.access;
})
```

Unforunately the 'Set-Cookie' header from the NestJS API has no effect in NuxtJS - So the cookies are not set.

How can I solve this problem? I tried to google a bit but found no clear answer.